# GetElementByID returns null value

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

I'm trying to add an validation on my project using javascript but my javascript function doesn't return the values if I use the GetElementByID function.
So, my php script is like:

```
<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()"> 
    //blah blah
</select><span></span>

<div id="divDep">
```

Important is the action onClick

And my javascript:

```
function getListaDep( ) {
        var IDDep ;
        IDDep= document.getElementById(IDDep).value;

        var strURL="ajax_page/findDepTranz.php?&IDDep="+IDDep;

        var req = getXMLHTTP();     
        if (req) {          
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {            
                        document.getElementById('divDep').innerHTML=req.responseText;   
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }               
    }
```

The findDepTranz.php

```
<?php
$IDDep = intval($_GET['IDDep']);
?>

<div>
    <?php echo 'IDDep: '.$IDDep; ?>
</div>
```

This example doesn't return me the IDDep but if I put instead: `onClick="getListaDep(this.value)"`  and in javascript:

```
 function getListaDep(IDDep ) {             
        var strURL="ajax_page/findDepTranz.php?&IDDep="+IDDep;
.... if works.
```

I need to return 2 values like IDDep, and my document.getElementById(IDDep).value doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have your tried to change `document.getElementById(IDDep).value;` to `document.getElementById('IDDep').value;` and `<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()"> `to `<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep() id="IDDep"> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the ID:

```
IDDep= document.getElementById('IDDep').value;
```

You also need to change the `select` so it has an ID:

```
<select name="IDDep" id="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()"> 
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: plz see `OP` question carefully, he is using `onclick` event on `select` element that is funny.. FYI `select` have not an `id`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If the value is being submited than haveing a name is quite usefull

Comment: @SuperDJ: Yes, but if you want to use `getElementById`, you need to give the element an `id`. It can *also* have a `name`... (Or, of course, you can use `querySelector` instead, using the name...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think he was just reacting to your use of _rather than_ -- that implies removing the `name` attribute when you add `id`.

Comment: Yes Barmar, this little id="IDDep" resolved my problem, but now i have to send 2 values, the second one is hidden in php, IDRef. Can you help me with this please? Sorry for my english....

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('IDRef').value`, and add another parameter to the URL.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Now that i see, i don't know way it was so difficult to me! :| Thank you! :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
change

```
IDDep = document.getElementById(IDDep).value;
```

to

```
IDDep = document.getElementById('IDDep').value; //Quoting the id
```

and

```
<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()">
```

to

```
<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()" id="IDDep">
```

Then in your javascript do the following

```
document.getElementById('IDDep').addEventListener('change', function() {
   //Your function here
});
//You can change 'change' to 'click' aswell if you need to
```

This also allows you to remove the onclick so

```
<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" onClick="getListaDep()" id="IDDep">
```

becomes

```
<select name="IDDep" style="width:152px" id="IDDep">
```